# Is there some way I can pass a reference to an Angular model to a scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several `canvas` areas in a web app to capture peoples' signatures, on official documentation. I am busy trying to develop a popup, to provide a larger area for the user to sign on, on smaller devices. The signature areas are something like this:

```
<canvas width="400" height="200" ng-signature ng-model="Party1.SignatureBase64"></canvas>
<a href="" ng-click="getSignatureModal(Party1.SignatureBase64)">Show Signature Pad</a>
```

Then I have the following function on the view scope that pops up a modal to gather signature data, but with JavaScript's "by value" passing, I am stuck with how to return the value from the function to the model.

```
$scope.getSignatureModal = function (signatureBase64) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'signatureWindow.html',
        controller: 'SignatureModalController',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            base64: function () {
                return signatureBase64;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (base64) {
        signatureBase64 = base64;
        return base64;
    }, function () {
        alert('Canceled');
    });
};
```

I could update my ng-click to:

```
ng-click="Party1.SignatureBase64=getSignatureModal(Party1.SignatureBase64)"
```

but that seems to be getting a bit unwieldy. Or is that the best way?

Comment: I'd do that with a $broadcast from the modal.  Retrofit the controller to receive a model as the payload on a message and you decouple it from the modal implementation.  A while back, I created a fiddle that uses $rootScope as a message broker. I'm not sure I have enough domain information to know for sure if this will be performant for what you need, but you can check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/kalanbates/dpb5x0vf/.

Comment: I think that ng-modal has the scope property, maybe you can pass the scope to reference the "$modalInstance" with your main controller. {controller: 'SignatureModalController', size: 'lg', scope: $scope, ...}

Comment: @wZVanG I like this idea, but how do I tell the modal what scope property it must use? If I have access to scope, I can pass a modal name, but I balk at the idea of using 'eval'.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that by injecting $rootScope and `$broadcast`ing from the modal.

Retrofit the controller to receive a model as the payload on a message and you decouple it from the modal implementation. A while back, I created a fiddle that uses `$rootScope` as a message broker. I'm not sure I have enough information of your specific domain to know for sure that this will be performant for what you need, but you can check it out at [$rootScope as a Message Broker](http://jsfiddle.net/kalanbates/dpb5x0vf)

View

```
<div ng-controller="Messenger">
   <input ng-model="message" style="width:100px">
   <input ng-model="target" style="width:87px" >
   <button ng-click="handleClick(message,target);">Send Message</button>
</div>

 <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
     <input ng-model="message" >
 </div>

 <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
     <input ng-model="message" >
 </div>
```

Selected Angular stuffs

```
var myModule = angular.module('MessageOrientedModule', []);
myModule.factory('messagingService', function($rootScope) {
var service = {};

service.notify = function(message, recipient, type){
    var payload = {};
    Object.defineProperty(payload,"recipient",{value:recipient});
    Object.defineProperty(payload,"body",{value:message});

    $rootScope.$broadcast(type,payload);
};


return service;
});

function Messenger($scope, messagingService) {
   $scope.handleClick = function(message,target) {
       messagingService.broadcastSpecific(message,target);
   };

   $scope.$on('message.broadcast', function(event, message) {
       $scope.message = message.body + ' [SENT]';
});}

function ControllerOne($scope) {
   $scope.$on('message.broadcast', function(event, data) {
       if(data.recipient != "Ctrl1")
       {
           $scope.message = '123 Not it!';
       }
       else
       {
          $scope.message = '[Ctrl1][Received]:' + data.body;
       }
   });
}

function ControllerTwo($scope) {
   $scope.$on('message.broadcast', function(event,data) {
       if(data.recipient != "Ctrl2")
       {
           $scope.message = '123 Not it!';
       }
       else
       {
         $scope.message = '[Ctrl2][Received]:' + data.body;
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very educational answer, but this still leaves me with how to 'return' the altered signature model from the function that receives the message from the modal. My problem isn't returning the signature from the modal, but from the function that invokes the modal.

My only, very novice, idea for straight up messaging, is to have a receiver function on each controller that has a model that the modal might change, and have the modal broadcast the model name as well as the model data, then set the scope property by name somehow.

Comment: The receiver(assuming this is a controller) of the "altered signature model" would inject the MessagingService and the "Messenger" functions would need to be implemented on the receiving controller as well. Let your Receiver put the incoming model into a message and broadcast it from $rootScope.  My advice would be to make the message type specific to a particular task rather than setting a "targetRecipient."